# Does order of the basis matter while creating a vector space and a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Im certain that order doesn't matter while creating vector spaces, but does it matter while creating linear transformations

Comment: No, but as soon a you write the transformation as a matrix, order *does* matter very much.

Comment: It's  not at all clear to me what you mean.

Comment: When we want to specify a basis with a definite order of its elements, we call that an *ordered basis*.  However you don't need to specify a basis merely to "create" a vector space, nor do you necessarily need to reference a basis in defining a linear transformation.  As @GyroGearloose is telling you, the *representation* of a linear transformation by a matrix does depend on the choice of an ordered basis (or bases, if a different basis is chosen for the domain and the co-domain).

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a 2-dimensional vector space with base vectors $\{\vec\alpha,\,\vec a\}$. (It is a horribly style to use symbols from two different alphabets, but I intentionally write it this way to not suggest any implicit ordering.)

This vector space does not depend on the order of the base vectors. But as soon as you use notations like $\vec v=(x,y)$ instead of $\vec v=x\vec a+y\vec\alpha$, the order matters a lot.

The same holds for transformations. If you define $\varphi(x\vec a+y\vec\alpha)= x\varphi(\vec a)+y\varphi(\vec\alpha)$ then nothing depends on the order of the base vectors.

As soon as you use matrices to represent transformations, the order of the base vectors is essential.

Comment: Thank you, your comment did the work but thank you for the explanation

Comment: @godmode So if you think the answer would be good enough for further visitor on this page, you can accept it.